# Adding bootstrap progress bar classes in javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

I've got the following javascript code. It's doing everything perfectly fine, except for the part where i add the css classes 'progress-striped' and 'active'. It doesn't display an active striped progress bar.

What am i doing wrong here?

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function(){

            window.percent = 0;

            window.progressInterval  = window.setInterval(function() {

                    var $bar = $('.progress');

                    if(window.percent < 100) {
                            window.percent = (window.percent + 2);
                            $bar.addClass('progress-striped').addClass('active');
                            $bar.width(window.percent+'%');
                            $bar.text(window.percent+'%');

                    } else if(window.percent == 100) {
                            window.clearInterval(window.progressInterval);
                            jQuery('.progress').removeClass('active');
                            $bar.text('Done!');
                    }
            }, 100);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.progress')
```

Shouldnt that be

```
$('.progress')
```

I think that might be the problem, else add a fiddle

Comment: I changed it, but that was at the else if part of the code. It's just making the bar striped and active that doesnt work.

Comment: Ok it seems that i used the wrong class at the beginning. var $bar = $('progress'); is changed to var $bar = $('progress-bar');